# How to search for a not equals value on a multi line nawk output

Tags: nawk

I have this current solution for CVS status managment:-

```
cvs -q status|awk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=1 a=9 s='(Locally Modified)|(Needs Patch)'
```

This gives me a display of Locally Modified files and files that need patching, which is great.
However a better solution for me that would catch all status is when the status is not equal to 'Up-to-date'.
I have tried s!= and s<> but it only seems to allow =.

Answer (score 0):

A little whitespace will go a long way...

The opposite of `$0 ~ s` is `$0 !~ s`, so

```
cvs -q status | awk '
    c-- > 0
    $0 !~ s {
        if (b)
            for (c=b+1; c>1; c--)
                print r[(NR-c+1)%b]
        print
        c=a
    }
    b {r[NR%b]=$0}
' b=1 a=9 s='Up-to-date'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its a lot easier to see whats going on in that format.
However adding the ! to ~s give me very odd results, it shows all the "Up-to-date" status and repeats the relating lines over and over.
Any ideas?

Comment: Yes: what is `c-- > 0` doing? It will print all the lines where c>0. Try removing it.